# Excel multiple conditional if from 2 sheets

Tags: excel

In Excel i have 2 sheets:
Sheet1 has 2 columns - A, B
Sheet2 has 3 columns - A, B, C

I want to show in Sheet1 the value of Sheet2's column C if Sheet1!A==Sheet2!A AND Sheet1!B==Sheet2!B

Sheet1:

Columns: A  | B   | [C(Value from Sheet2)]

Row1: a|  1|   100

Row2:  a|   2|   200

Row3:  b  |  1  | 300

Row4:  b   | 2|   700

Sheet2:

A   |   B  | C

a    |  1  |  100

b      | 1|    300

a     |  2   | 200

b      | 2 |   700

How can this be implemented?
Thanks

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but please do at least a bit of research before asking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show what you have tried, what is not working, preferably use english instead of 10x, etc. Simple internet search leads to https://exceljet.net/formula/if-this-and-that

Comment: If you had read my entire question and try to understand it instead of "not been harsh" you would see that what you gave me is irrelevant. If the 10x is what bothering you i will edit and remove it. 10x.

Comment: In general the quality and usefulness of answers seems to depend on the "quality" of the question and how easy it is to understand. The question is still confusing, but based on the example it seems like you want to **find** or **[double lookup](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+double+lookup)** the values. This is usually done with `Index`+`Match` or `VLookUp` array formula, but it might be easier to join/merge the tables with Power Query or Microsoft Query.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have Excel on this Linux machine, so this may not be totally
correct, but you do an `AND` this way:

```
=AND(condition1,condition2,...)
```

So you would use something like this:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!B1),Sheet1!C1,"something else")
```

Next time, please look at the available functions, google around a
little. You will not get much sympathy here if you don’t do your
homework before asking.